# Interactive callback is not longer called on user input

Tags: python, interactive

I am trying to make an interactive example using `sh` python library.

Taken the idea from [interactive-callbacks documentation](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/asynchronous_execution.html#interactive-callbacks) I wrote two simple scripts.

```
# test_example1.py
import sh

def interact(line, stdin):
    if "Hello" in line:
        stdin.put("me\n")
        return True # end
    print(f">> line: {line}")


print("-Start-")
response = sh.example1(_out=interact, _bg=True)
response.wait()
print("-End-")
```

and the shell script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# example1
echo Good Morning, sir.
echo -n Hello, who am I talking to?:
read varname
echo It\'s nice to meet you $varname
```

but in console the program does not continue reading more lines

```
-Start-
>> line: Good Morning, sir.
(no more chars, so the input is never shown)
```

digging in the code, it seems like the poll selector is never awaken with the  `echo -n Hello, who am I talking to?:`

removing `-n' flag letting '\n' to be written fix the issue, but is not the case as some script prompts and wait the response in the same line.

I tried to use different combination of flags without any positive results.
The `sh` library looks amazing, so I am sure I am doing missing.

Can anyone help me to write some interactive example?

Comment: The [tag:sh] tag is for the Bourne shell itself, not a Python library with the same name.

Comment: I'm guessing the `echo -n` is throwing off the library; it's probably using buffered I/O, and so nothing happens until it sees a newline (or a huge amount of output which forces the buffer to be flushed).

Comment: [The documentation](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#out-bufsize) suggests setting `_out_bufsize` to 0 to disable buffering.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee

`response = sh.example1(_out=interact, _bg=False, _out_bufsize=0)` will me call each char character, giving me the chance to compose the whole line and apply some regexpr later on.

Answer (score 0):

A basic recipe for understanding the plumbing:

```
import sh
def interact(**rules):
    buffer = ''
    def process(chunk, stdin, process):
        nonlocal buffer
        buffer += chunk
        for regexp, answer in rules.items():
            if re.search(regexp, buffer):
                stdin.put(answer + '\n')
                buffer=''
    return process

sh.example1(_out=interact(talking='me'), _out_bufsize=0)
```

can interact with prompts like python `input` or bash `read` that do not sent  lines ending with `\n`.

finally using a more compact call style:

```
import sh

def reply(**kwargs):
    kw = dict(_out_bufsize=0)
    rules = {}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if k[0] == '_':
            kw[k] = v
        else:
            rules[k] = v
        kw['_out'] = interact(**rules)
    return kw


def interact(**rules):
    buffer = ''
    def process(chunk, stdin, process):
        nonlocal buffer
        buffer += chunk
        for regexp, answer in rules.items():
            if re.search(regexp, buffer):
                stdin.put(answer + '\n')
                buffer=''

    return process

sh.example1(**reply(talking='me'))
```